# presentViewController - view solid black, viewDid___ methods not called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, modalviewcontroller

```
    ...
    SecondViewController *svc = [SecondViewController new];
    [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

This code is exactly the same as what I used in another app, but here I'm using `presentViewController` rather than `presentModalViewController`
(`completion:NULL` makes them effectively identical. Same result, at least.)

Both attempts at creating a modal view are structured the same way. Those lines in the main view, a view controller in the Storyboard, and matching `.h` and `.m` files.  The only difference is that here I want a programmatic trigger, so it's impossible to drag a segue and be done with it.
I have an object set to recognize a gesture and call the transition method. That's probably what's causing the problem (part of it, at least), but it is necessary.

Using a UIButton would be cheating. No deadline, no shortcuts.

**EDIT:** NSLog output shows something odd.

`2012-04-05 10:41:12.047 MyApp[5962:707] <SecondViewController: 0x1d8c130>`
`2012-04-05 10:41:12.479 MyApp[5962:707] <SecondViewController: 0x1d8e360>`

So I'm doing something stupid again that happens to have a very simple fix, right?
Edit again: `presentViewController…` was being called more than once. Fixed it. Still black, though.

---

Back to `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` instead of the much easier `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException", reason: 'Receiver … has no segue with identifier …'

I told it to perform a segue, but there isn't one in the Storyboard (I *can't* add one, there is no Storyboard Segues section under 'Connections inspector' for the object I'm attempting to use), so it crashes. This is normal behavior.

What I want is to have a modal view *without* needing to create a segue. I've done it, so I know it's possible.
All I need is a bit of help getting it to work.

.

`performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Identifier" sender:nil` **NSSInvalidArgumentException**
`presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL` **Empty View**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it.

Replace the lines in the question with this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard"
                                                     bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *viewController =
            [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondView"];
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Credit for this solution goes to IturPablo's self-answered question:
[TabBarController, overwriting shouldSelectViewController to do a segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589538/tabbarcontroller-overwriting-shouldselectviewcontroller-to-do-a-segue)

Comment: hey bro, good answer, ur a rockstar bro! Love that shit! thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`?  The docs seem to match your description:

> "you can call this method to trigger a segue programmatically, perhaps
>   in response to some action that cannot be specified in the storyboard
>   resource file"

Comment: That wasn't working at all (error was something about receiver not having a segue identifier) so I figured I'd fall back on the simpler present/dismiss modal view.

Comment: That error **usually** comes up for me if I happen to connect the start of the segue in the storyboard to a controller that's not the one that I call the method on.

Comment: I made sure all the names of views/identifiers/etc were correct. Even if I had managed to get it to work, it would still require that I rework the UI to fit another button. (This view (which isn't actually called "Second") was not planned, so there isn't much room to fit another object.)

Comment: You don't need a button for this; it's a completely programmatic way of presenting a new view controller. Segues belong to view controllers, not buttons. It sounds like you didn't set an identifier for the segue itself in the storyboard file.

Comment: I know I don't, that's why I put a question on SO. // There are no empty "Identifier" fields in the Storyboard, so I don't know why Xcode would be complaining about one missing. Doesn't matter if I can get the modal option working.

Comment: Using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` is the correct way to do what you're asking. If the receiver doesn't have a segue with the identifier you specified, your storyboard is set up wrong, and you should focus on solving that problem, not trying to work around it.

Comment: I set my storyboard up the same was as always. The only difference is that, because I'm using an object that cannot be the sender of a Storyboard Segue (not with a click-drag from IB, anyway), I have to write the transition myself. // I'll put `performSegue…` back in and see what happens. | Edit: Nothing happens now. The call is ignored.

Comment: You can specify `nil` for the sender if you're performing it programmatically; the only place that matters is in your `prepareForSegue:sender:` implementation. If you don't implement that method, there's no need to set a sender at all.

Comment: Still nothing new or useful. I'm almost to the point of considering a Custom UIButton, but then the last few hours would go to waste. Not ideal.